# Cordova Plugin - Is there a tool to generate JS interface automatically?

Tags: android, cordova, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins

Just want to know if is there any tool to generate the `Javascript` interface for a `Cordova Plugin` automatically?

That would be very helpful.

For example, once you are done with the native part of a `Cordova Plugin`, for example on this tutorial:

https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/createplugintutorial/

When you arrive to the `Step 3` you need to create the `Javascript` plugin. How is that process?, is there any way to make it easy?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of one. There are probably a couple reasons for this:

- IIRC, the whole idea of plugins as a separate thing from the core functionality of Cordova was not very well defined prior to the [Cordova 3.x release](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/releases/2013/07/23/cordova-3.html). Even afterwards, it took a while for things to standardize on `npm` as a plugin repository. Someone with a better memory might be able to fill this in.
- There's not much incentive for the Cordova guys to create a plugin interface tool. Most of their clients' (read: *our*) dev work is in the HTML5 layer -- plugins are mostly just a polyfill to the stuff that HTML5 can't get to on the device.